# How do I read the stats on article pages on the Magic: The Gathering Website?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015, magic-the-gathering-online

I am a new player and I'm doing some research on meta decks. Some of the articles on the Magic website have a stats section when talking about certain decks and I can't figure how how to read them. I've attached a screenshot of what I am talking about. The middle and right charts are self-explanatory, but I am more interested in knowing how to read the left chart.

[image: stats]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about a website's interface, not a game.

Comment: @Frank From what the question is describing, these are statistics about global in-game mechanics which can be directly used to modify/improve your own personal in-game mechanics, and the stats are released by the official developers of the game. I think the question certainly on topic.

Comment: @Magexy Its about a website. Granted, the website can be used for the video game, but it can also be used for the card game. We definitely don't support the card game, and the same distinction applies to the website. Its not a game, therefore, not our area. The question isn't even about a specific video game, which just makes it even less applicable for us.

Comment: @Frank But OP isn't asking about the card game, they're asking about the video game (based on the tags). I guess we can vote as we deem fit. I personally don't think it's off-topic. If these stats were available in-game in a menu somewhere, it wouldn't be off-topic... so just because it's on an external website, we can't answer it anymore? I'd even agree with you if the website was some third party, but it's the official game developers' website.

Comment: @Magexy The question has tags, but nowhere is the game mentioned at all. This is specifically about the website and how to read it. Why do we we support websites? Even official ones? Why should we? We're not UI experts; we're gamers. We don't support questions about wiki sites, and a website being official makes no difference. Its not a game. We don't support it.

Comment: @Frank 1) On Arqade, if a question is tagged with a game name, unless it's obviously mistagged, I give them the benefit of doubt and assume it's about the video game version(s) and not the off-topic card game version. 2) You're right, the website is not a game... but the information that is shown is sourced directly from the game (afaik) and is very obviously relevant to how players will end up playing the game.

Comment: We've both made our points, let's just agree to disagree and let the votes decide whether this question is good or not.

Comment: Hey. Sorry if my post was not crystal clear about the game I was playing. Obviously Magic: The Gathering is a card game, however I am playing Magic: Duels on Xbox One. The exact same principles apply and I could not find a proper tag other than mtg-online. I also couldn't create my own tag because I don't have enough rep.

Comment: I think the question is valid because it doesn't really relate to the website. It more relates to reading the type of deck the player was using. I assume that the graph is used widely in Magic and that most players would know what that means (except me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are mana costs to cast cards in your deck. The numbers represent the total amount of mana to cast. For instance, if you have a card that costs 2 green and 1 blue, it will fall under the 3-cost pile.

My guess for the 23 0-cost cards is that they are primarily lands, as 1/3 is roughly the recommended amount of lands for a deck. In general, you want as many cards to be on the left end of that spectrum as possible, as it's not always guaranteed that you'll have enough lands to cast the more expensive cards.